# Automation using Pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, python-2.x, pyautogui

My system will goes to sleep if there is no keyboard and mouse action for more than 5 min ( I cannot make any changes in sleep time. For security reason it is set to 5 min).

I am using pyautogui for automation. Pyautogui works in background based on screen resolution by taking keyboard and mouse control. It is taking more than 5 min in my case to complete the execution. After 5 min it going to sleep and keyboard interrupt is generated.

Please let me know is there any solution for these.

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the goal of pyautogui?

Comment: Windows. Login to server, executing some commands and capturing screenshot.

Comment: Is the goal to prevent Windows from sleeping?

Comment: Yes, Somehow I need prevent Windows from sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the mouse all time and deactivate it by taking your mouse to upper left corner:

```
import pyautogui as p

p.FAILSAFE = True # enables the fail-safe
distance = 200
while True:
    p.moveRel(distance, 0, duration=0.5)   # move right
    distance -= 5
    p.moveRel(0, distance, duration=0.5)   # move down
    p.moveRel(-distance, 0, duration=0.5)  # move left
    distance -= 5
    p.moveRel(0, -distance, duration=0.5)  # move up
    distance +=10
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've found to work is running the pyautogui script in a virtual machine, which lets it use the virtual mouse & keyboard. This has the twofold benefit of a. allowing you to do other work while the script is running, and b. the virtual mouse & keyboard are not interrupted with the computer going to sleep.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for some action to be completed, you can simulate a minor mouse movement in a new thread. This will prevent system from sleep.

Comment: Manually I need to do some mouse action?

Comment: Not manually. Just move the mouse (little bit) in script itself. Use another thread so your script will wait for the long running action to complete in first / main thread, and still be able to do mouse action in other thread.